# How to prevent Ionic view titles from replacing html head titles

Tags: ionic-framework

We are using the ionic framework. We have an html title tag in our parent page's head i.e. `<title>our app</title>`. This seems to get overwritten in our login page when using `<ion-view title="Login">` and it sometimes get's overridden in other pages I can't really figure out why certain ones do get overridden and others don't.

We want the parent's page title to remain the title throughout the entire app. I would take out the ion-view title but it gives our pages headers, which we still want.

Comment: I'd like to know if you found the solution for this problem?

Comment: Yes I did I will add the answer that I found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was adding titles like so:

```
<ion-view title="login">
```

this was in order to get the title in the top nav bar when I added the titles like this instead I would get the titles in the nav bar without affecting the title of the page.

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>Emergency Contacts</ion-nav-title>
    ...
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I was working on mobile web app that could be attached to home screen on android (chrome) or iphone(safari). It was annoying that the suggested name of the app shortcut was for example "login".

Then I found about Web app manifest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest

You can set your app name, icon and background of splashscreen... It worked out great for me.. So ididn't even have to fix the page title.

I hope someone find this useful.